# Align image inside div to the middle vertically

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image inside a div. I crop the image by having a fixed height on the div and `overflow: hidden`. How do I align the image inside to the middle **vertically**?

So, to visualize my aim:

[image]

1. Full image of cat.
2. How it is currently looking when the image is cropped.
3. How I want it to look. The image is aligned to the middle vertically and cropped accordingly.

Please note that the height of the image varies (user uploaded).

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hay8dpx/) for testing.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qRkEJni.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container img{
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: It's working for me with your code in codepen and jsfiddle

Comment: @SaucedApples Please read the question properly. The cropping works, but I want to align the image to the middle **vertically**. I even added an image to avoid confusion. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternate way:

```
.container img {
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hay8dpx/5/)**

Comment: The jsfiddle link is wrong, but I see where you are going. Very interesting. What's the browser compatibility with this approach?

Comment: yes, updated. it's compatible with all browser, IE higher than 10.

Answer (score 4):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.container {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container img{
    height:auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qRkEJni.jpg">
</div>
```

or absolute positioning.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qRkEJni.jpg">
</div>
```

Or...of course, using a background image instead.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/qRkEJni.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: What's the browser compatibility of using flex-box? I experienced some problems with it earlier on android browser and IE browsers.